# Is PEPPOL Envelope sender the same as EHF Billing 3.0 AccountingCustomerParty?

Tags: billing, invoice

When sending an EHF Billing 3.0 Invoice, one must supply information about the customer and the supplier.
The invoice is sent along with a Standard Business Document Header (SBDH) that specify sender and receiver of the document.

Does the sender equivalent to the AccountingCustomerParty? And the receiver to AccountingSupplierParty?

And is it necessary to query the SML/SMP for all registrants?

Answer (score 0):

The [PEPPOL BIS Billing 3.0 syntax binding](https://docs.peppol.eu/poacc/billing/3.0/syntax/ubl-invoice/tree/) contains information on how to understand the different parts of the invoice document.

Comment: I have been studying this in details the last 4 months, and the syntax for Payment Request two months before that. Still, this does not answer the question about any relationship between Billing 3.0 syntax and SBDH sender/receiver. And it does not say if one should query the SML register before sending to the assumed participants, say if their configuration is not longer valid.

Comment: @pekaaw I also have to generate and send EHF invoices via peppol networks, how did you do these creation, validation and sending of invoices? what did you use? any github link or anything, it's a very unknown tech stack for me

Comment: @JuliyanageSilva I'm afraid I have no good answer for you, and I wish I knew this tech stack. We use a PEPPOL access point implementation called Oxalis from <https://github.com/OxalisCommunity/oxalis>. It is a java implementation, so we have a separate server running this endpoint, and another api to generate an EHF based on a simpler dataset, as well as a validation api we use before sending. I can only wish you luck.

Comment: @pekaaw thanks for the info, so you wrote generating and sending by yourselves?

Comment: @JuliyanageSilva I created an internal service where I wrote an api for generating EHF xml with or without SBDH according to the syntax documentation referred to in this answer. A collegue created another internal service with two api endpoint. One for sending EHF, which works as a wrapper around Oxalis. The other one for validation, which works as a wrapper around another library called vefa validator <https://github.com/anskaffelser/vefa-validator>.

Comment: @pekaaw sorry I have another question, did you ran oxalis in windows or linux? the guide seems only for linux, if it is windows did you find a guide for that?

Comment: @JuliyanageSilva I did not install this myself, but I can see that it is a Java application running on a TomCat server on Windows.

Comment: @pekaaw thanks mate, there are some issues as in it's highest natural habitat as usual, let's see

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the sender and receiver in the business document header would be your technical endpoints through the PEPPOL network

PartyIdentfication information on AccountingCustomerParty gives you the actual business identification of the buyer
Ref: https://docs.peppol.eu/poacc/billing/3.0/2023-Q2/syntax/ubl-invoice/cac-AccountingCustomerParty/cac-Party/cac-PartyIdentification/

It is the same tags / value across all ubl invoice document variants

Envelope (SBDH) description:
https://docs.peppol.eu/edelivery/envelope/PEPPOL-EDN-Business-Message-Envelope-1.2.1-2020-03-11.pdf
Please note: It is the communication layer which adds the envelope not the integration / business layer